# Access Firefox web console via Linux/Ubuntu shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, firefox, ubuntu, console

I have a shellscript (ubuntu /bin/bash) that pulls html-pages, extracts plaintext, makes an index of all pages etc. Now I need screenshots of the webpages.

I tried a lot of linux command line tools like webkit2png, cutycapt and shutter. They all could not get the right output. Webkit2png was the best, but there is an error in the qt4 library that makes it impossible for me.

The screenshot command of the new firefox console is perfect, the page is rendered as I need it.

Is it possible to run a command of the web console of firefox via a shell script, I think of something like ">firefox --webconsole=screenshot http://www.domain.com" ?

Comment: You just want to take a screenshot? something like `scrot` isn't enough?

Comment: Scrot does not fit my needs, I need the whole webpage with scrolling down.